# How to calculate the length of a line which is perpendicular to another knowing three coordinates?

Tags: geometry

I am sure this is something completely dumb but my mathematics is, well awful, so be kind...

I know three coordinates (2D standard x and y things where the top left is 0,0 and the x increases from left to right and y increases from top to bottom) and I can plot a line between two of them and then make a third point where the intersection with the line should be 90 degrees and what I want to calculate is the length of the line that made this angle (I am sure if I could explain myself properly I would have found an answer to this already).

Here is a picture of what I mean (with some example values for the three coordinates A, B and C that are known to me):

[image: diagram]

So, how do I calculate the length marked L in the above?

I thought, well, the line L is normal to the vector A to B so I could say...

The vector from A to B is (4, 7) and therefore the normal vectors would be (-7, 4) and (7, -4) but then I am stuck - where do I go now?  Am I even on the right track?

Comment: The red line is often called "dropping a perpendicular" in geometry. Optional reading material: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Comment: @anon Thanks!  That was all I needed (you could put that as an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the easiest way I can think of:

- Find the normal vector for $AB$.
- Take the dot product of the normal vector and $A$.
- Take the dot product of the normal vector and $C$.
- Subtract the two dot products.
- Divide by the length of the normal vector.

The result is the length of $L$.

Per your example:

- $N = B-A = (7, -4)$.
- $a = N \cdot A = (1 \cdot 7) + (1 \cdot -4) = 7 - 4 = 3$.
- $c = N \cdot C = (7 \cdot 7) + (-4 \cdot 5) = 49 - 20 = 29$.
- $c - a = 29 - 3 = 26$.
- $|N| = \sqrt{7^2 + 4^2} = \sqrt{49 + 16} = \sqrt{65} \approx 8.062$.
- $26 \div 8.062 \approx 3.225$.

So $L$ is about 3.225 units long.

Comment: The normal vector alone isn't sufficient to find the distance. To see why, notice that all parallel lines have the same normal vector, but their distances from a fixed point change depending on where the line is located in the plane.

Comment: You are of course correct. Give me a minute to fix my answer...

Comment: @AymanHourieh: Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

What you want a [point-line distance in 2D](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Calculus/DistanceToLine.shtml).

Let's calculate the formula of $AB$:

$$
y-y_A = \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A} (x-x_A)
$$

Plug and simplify:

$$
7x -4y -3 = 0
$$

Now let's use the point-line distance formula:

\begin{align*}
d &= \frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \\
&= \frac{|7\times7+(-4)\times5+(-3)|}{\sqrt{7^2+(-4)^2}} \\
&= \frac{26}{\sqrt{65}} \approx 3.224
\end{align*}